# Cannot use 'fread' to files of 3+ Gb - Python datatable

Tags: python, datatable

Recently I've started to use [datatable](https://datatable.readthedocs.datatableo/en/latest/index.html) to manipulate data and faced the following issue:

The `fread()` function used to read 3+ GB files returns the error message.
At the same moment pandas reads this file without any issues.

The code and error message are below:

Code:

```
import datatable as dt

data = dt.fread(file='LF.csv')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 D:/.../datatable test.py:8 in <module>  data = dt.fread(file='LF.csv')

IOError: Unable to obtain size of LF.csv: [errno 132] value too large
```

Could someone advice on that please?
If any additional information is needed please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please file an issue at https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues.

Comment: i get the same error. did you find a solution to this? my file is about 30M rows