# the error message of reading a large size csv file using datatable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code script to open a `csv file`:

```
    import datatable as dt
    file_path=os.path.join(root_path, "train.csv")
    print('file_path is ',file_path)
    dt.fread(file_path)
```

**While running this code it  gives the following error**.

```
 file_path is  D:\.kaggle\data\janestreet\train.csv
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-29-1c38daf7b1ed> in <module>
      2 file_path=os.path.join(root_path, "train.csv")
      3 print('file_path is ',file_path)
----> 4 dt.fread(file_path)
    
IOError: Unable to obtain size of D:.kaggledatajanestreettrain.csv: [errno 132] value too large
```

Comment: Seems like a similar issue to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64534891/cannot-use-fread-to-files-of-3-gb-python-datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think You Can Use Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)
print(df)
```